# Cannot access 'interceptor' before initialization in karma with angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

```
type here
```

Im using functional interceptor in angular 17, this works with `ng serve` but when trying run unit test i get this error:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'urlInterceptor' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'urlInterceptor' before initialization
at Module.urlInterceptor (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:398:61)
...
```

My testing file:
todo-item.component.spec.ts

```
describe('component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...
      providers: [
        TodosService,
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([urlInterceptor])),
        provideHttpClientTesting()
      ],
      ...
    })
    .compileComponents();
    ...
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I try deleting all other .spec files, providing HttpClientModule in tradicional way, changing the import order in .spec file and app.config.ts file, but nothing works.

Comment: You need provide more info on your question. Can you put a reproducable example on StackBlitz?